# Facebook API friends work and education recent changes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Looking at Bright website, I'm trying to figure out how they achieve their Latest Activity pane. Basically, sign in with Facebook on their website gave me all my friends work recent changes, ordered by date. Take a look here to see what I mean:

[image: bright activity]

This is what I've done at this time so far:

- Used `friends_work_history` permission and retrieve work field like `/me/friends?fields=name,work` with Graph API. While that gives me friends work history as well as their current position, I still can't obtain the date of the latest change of their current work employer.
- Looking into the `feed` object (also using Graph API) as well as the `stream` object (using this time FQL) of my friends, to see if I could filter work changes. Still no luck. I just can't find any story or activity related to their work.

Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that's rather impossible to obtain such friends work changes with date. In the best world, what we would like to achieve is, when a user uses our website for the first time, and sign in using Facebook, we would like to show them such "Latest Activity" as you can see from the image from Bright.

If that's really not possible, we will forget the idea of seeing an history of the lastest work updates among friends, and we will focus of taking a "snapshot" of the present, and work from there. We could try either:

- Using our own tracking system, which will basically consist of pooling the Facebook Graph API at some time during the day to see if we could find any changes in the work history of user's friends.

OR

- Maybe use the Real-time Updates service of Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/, which could maybe allow us to track these kind of changes. But the more I think about it, the more I guess it will not work since it will not allow us to track changes on friends work field.

Anyway, maybe someone was able to solve that problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get at this using FQL. I can't find a friend who changed jobs recently, so I can't validate what this should be.

Using something like this:

```
SELECT post_id, message, type, attribution, description,description_tags FROM stream 
  WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()) AND 
  strpos(description,"added a job") > 0
```

Should get you those posts. My guess is that these have a unique `type` value, where you can filter these more efficiently.

Don't forget that the `stream` table is hobbled to return only the last 30 days worth of posts. You'll need to execute multiple queries to get at any significant history.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After some FQL testing, I found that "employer" is not the right word to use (only used on Bright website I guess). You should use "added a job" instead. Furthermore, I found that doing your query using `WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me())` only work for the last few days (at least, I found a friend who changed job in April using that query). I instead tried something like `WHERE source_id = [some_friend_uid]` which works in the past.

Comment: What I'm wondering now is, if for example I have 500 friends, I guess it would be overkill to manually do 500 queries, right? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: According to the documentation, the `stream` table is limited to return the greater of 50 results or the last 30 days worth of data. So you *should* be able to get that friend's data by adding `AND created_time < 2012-04-30` to your query. You should be able to get a year's data on all 500 of your friends in just 12 queries (or one multiquery).

Comment: FQL stream table is definitely inconsistent. I tried this simple query `SELECT created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = A_FRIEND_ID` which return me only 5 results (the last one is from Sep 4). Adding a simple `LIMIT 20` to that query, like this `SELECT created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = A_FRIEND_ID LIMIT 20` return me instead 13 results (last one from Aug 27, still in the 30 days range). Following the 50 results or the last 30 days worth of data, I should have been able to retrieve more than 5 posts in the first query. And why adding the `LIMIT 20` would return me more results then?